# Compiling C Program to WebAssembly Program with "Error: No available targets are compatible with this triple" on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: c, ubuntu, emscripten, webassembly

Following [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm), I tried to compile a C program to WebAssembly by using the following command.

```
emcc hello.c -s WASM=1 -o hello.html
```

But I ecounter the "`No available targets are compatible with this triple.`" problem.

```
$ emcc hello.c -s WASM=1 -o hello.html
WARNING  root: LLVM version appears incorrect (seeing "(https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp-clang/", expected "3.4")
INFO     root: (Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
WARNING  root: Assigning a non-existent settings attribute "WASM"
WARNING  root:  - did you mean one of ASM_JS?
WARNING  root:  - perhaps a typo in emcc's  -s X=Y  notation?
WARNING  root:  - (see src/settings.js for valid values)
/home/casper/Desktop/test/emsdk/clang/fastcomp/build_incoming_64/bin/lli: error creating EE: No available targets are compatible with this triple.
FAIL: Running the generated program failed!
```

How to solve it?

---

#### EMCC Version

```
$ emcc --version
emcc (Emscripten GCC-like replacement) 1.22.1 ()
Copyright (C) 2014 the Emscripten authors (see AUTHORS.txt)
This is free and open source software under the MIT license.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

#### Basic Information

```
OS           : Ubuntu 16.10
emcc Location: /usr/bin/emcc
```

Comment: Looks like perhaps your emscripten version is wrong.  Where is your emcc coming from (`which emcc`)?  It seems to be claiming that WASM is not in setting.js which means perhaps its old version?

Comment: The emcc installed is `emcc (Emscripten GCC-like replacement) 1.22.1`.

Answer (score 3):

You're running `emcc` version 1.22.1 which [dates back from 8/7/2014](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/introducing_emscripten/release_notes.html), before WebAssembly was started.

`emsdk` in the instruction you followed must have installed a very recent emscripten version (this is what `sdk-incoming-64bit` from these instructions does: `incoming` is the latest branch), but an older emscripten is found in your system.

Run:

```
which emcc
echo $PATH
```

What do they say? I suspect you have an old emscripten lying in there. You probably also want to check and/or delete your [`~/.emscripten` file](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emsdk.html#compiler-configuration-file) which may also contain obsolete information.

You can alter your path, delete the older emscripten, or invoke the SDK's emscripten using its absolute path (though this may fail later if other scripts pick up older versions along the path).

Don't forget (from the tutorial's instructions) to activate the SDK you've installed:

```
./emsdk activate --build=Release sdk-incoming-64bit binaryen-master-64bit
```

And run:

```
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

This last command needs to be run for every shell session. If you open a new shell you need to re-`source` then SDK.

Comment: When I execute `which emcc`, it shows me `/usr/bin/emcc`.

Comment: @Casper I added a bit more info to the answer. Make sure you've run `activate`, and `source`. If that doesn't work, delete `/usr/bin/emcc` and try `activate` / `source` again. Make sure to check `which emcc`.

Comment: Before I compile the Emscripten from source, I have installed the Emscripten from APT by using command `sudo apt-get install emscripten`. The emcc 1.22.1 should be from APT.

Comment: @Casper that's the problem then: the APT `emcc` is in your shell's `$PATH` before the SDK's `emcc`. Does running `source ./emsdk_env.sh` fix the issue for that terminal session?

Comment: After running `source ./emsdk_env.sh`, I can run `emcc` and `emrun` by using the full paths of them in the command line instead of just `emcc` and `emrun`.